# Orthonormal basis for boolean functions

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Consider the set of functions with domain $\{+1, −1\}^n$ and range $\mathbb R$. Observe that it is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ of dimension $2^n$. Consider the inner product and norm defined by
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{x\epsilon\{+1,-1\}^n} f(x)g(x) \quad and\quad \Vert f\Vert = \sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$$
a)Define the following functions:
$$\{\chi_S\}_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}} \quad where \quad \chi_S(x)=\prod_{i\epsilon S}x_i$$

For $S=\varnothing$, $\chi_S$ is the constant 1 function. Show that these functions form an orthonormal basis under the inner product defined.

b)Let f be any function this space with range $\{+1,-1\}$ such that
$$f=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}} \hat f_S\chi_S \quad where \quad \hat f_S\in \mathbb{R}$$
That is $(\widehat f_S)_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}}$ are the co-ordinates with respect to the $\chi_S$ basis.

Show that
$$\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}} (\widehat {f_S})^2=1$$

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to math.stackexchange! Could you tell us a bit about what you tried and where you are getting confused?

Comment: My attempt at the solution: In order to prove all the functions Xs(x) are orthonormal, I started by proving the norm of Xs , for any defined s, to be 1. As all the xi are either 1 or -1, so as Xs. Thus Xs(x)Xs(x) has to be 1. Now x can take 2^n distinct values. Therefore <Xs,Xs> becomes (1+1+ ...2^n times)/2^n = 1. So norm of any Xs(x) is 1. Now I proceeded to prove <Xs1 , Xs2> =0 to prove all Xs are orthonormal, for any defined s1 and s2. Now I am stuck here, as there are 2^n values of s for each x and 2^n values of x. How to generalise x and s and prove ahead?@Kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so I think $b)$ is clear from the fact that $\{\chi_S\}_S$ are orthogonal. Your argument for $\langle \chi_S,\chi_S\rangle=1$ is correct. So let us focus on
showing that $\langle \chi_S,\chi_R\rangle=0$ if $R\neq S$.

We have that

$$
\langle \chi_S,\chi_R\rangle=
2^{-n} \sum_{x \in \{-1,+1\}^{\{1,\dots,n\}}} \prod_{i\in S} x_i \prod_{j\in R} x_j.
$$
Notice that for each $x$ the indexes $i \in S\cap R$ do not contribute to the product as $x_i^2=1$, therefore we have that
$$
\prod_{i\in S} x_i \prod_{j\in R} x_j
=
\prod_{i\in S \Delta R} x_i,
\qquad (1)
$$
where $S \Delta R$ denotes the symmetric difference of $S$ and $R$.

Finally, we argue that for any non-empty set $J \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$, we have
$$
\sum_{x \in \{-1,+1\}^{\{1,\dots,n\}}} \prod_{i\in J} x_i =0. \qquad (2)
$$
Indeed, choose $j \in J$, we can write the right hand side as
$$
\sum_{x \in \{-1,+1\}^{\{1,\dots,n\}}} \prod_{i\in J} x_i 
=
\left(\sum_{x_j \in \{-1,1\}} x_j \right)\left(\sum_{x \in \{-1,+1\}^{\{1,\dots,n\} \setminus \{j\}}}  \prod_{i\in J \setminus \{j\}} x_i \right).
$$
Now the first term is equal to zero.

Finally, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have the desired result, as $S\neq R \iff S\Delta R \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: How to prove that the set {Xs} forms a basis? It is obvious that the orthogonal vectors are linearly independent. How to prove that {Xs} spans the entire vector space of all functions having the domain {+1,-1}^n ?

Comment: Notice that they are $2^n$ linearly independent vector, and we know that the dimension of this vector space is $2^n$.

Comment: The dimension can be derived from making another basis $f_{x} (y)= 1$ if $x=y$ and equal to $0$ if $x\neq y$. This is just the canonical basis of your space, moreover, notice that you have $2^n$ possibilities of $x \in \{-1,+1\}^n$.